# Can you write the shortest boolean formula for this truth table?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am looking the the shorted formula possible, can you help to simplyfy it?

((not A and B and C and not D) or (not A and B and C and D) or (A and not B and C and not D) or (A and not B and not C and D))

possibly with explaination of each step

y is the result and equal to 1

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Is $y$ the output and $x_1,\ldots, x_4$ input? Shall $y$ be $0$ for all other combinations of input values?

Comment: yes  it is correct

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map